# When Scrolling in RecyclerView automatically adds space in between rows

Tags: android, json, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have used RecyclerView to display some JSON data using Volley Library. I am getting the JSON data, but initially when data is displayed, it is in correct format. But when I scroll in recyclerview, then huge space is added in between rows.

Before Scrolling
[image: Before Scolling]

[image]

After Scrolling
Here is the XMl Part of row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the recyclerview added in xml

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your relativelayout's height to wrap_content in row.xml

```
  android:layout_height="wrap_content "
```

Comment: thanks, but why it was showing initially without any space??

Comment: I don't know, logically it should never show that way.

Comment: I have some other question

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: http://placehold.it/600/92c952  this is the link of an image in json data, but when i tried to display using this link in image_view, it is not displaying anything.

Comment: Try to load your image with picasso library, it is the best library for loading images I've ever used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117989/discussion-between-demo-mail-and-drv).

Comment: @Drv thats what i thought till i used fresco, i found fresco much better than picasso and that is after using both a while :)

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeholder(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame).into(holder.iv_image);

I am using url only, but unable to display image

Comment: i was accepting the answer, after 2 mins only.  But it said to wait for 10 mins.   Please help me for my second question also

Answer (score 0):

**but why it was showing initially without any space??**

ListView and RecycleView both have default height for view.
You use match_parent then it'll go with default height so due to that displaying white space at above.

If your TextView gravity will be center vertical then It'll display space at top and bottom both.

Answer (score 0):

Add `useCompatPadding="true"` in `single_row` of the recycler view xml. This may fix the issue. And also use height as "wrap content".